# Python understanding assert methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert

Im new in python. I have learning it since last month. I found website called exercism.io and started doing there some exercises. I have stopped on 2nd one. You can find there some "assert's class" which looks like:

```
class TwoFerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_no_name_given(self):
        self.assertEqual(two_fer(), "One for you, one for me.")

    def test_a_name_given(self):
        self.assertEqual(two_fer("Alice"), "One for Alice, one for me.")

    def test_another_name_given(self):
        self.assertEqual(two_fer("Bob"), "One for Bob, one for me.")
```

and the main code should be done by me. Good function which i should do is:

```
def two_fer(name):
    if name:
        return f'One for {name}, one for me.'
    elif not name:
        return "One for you, one for me."
```

The question is: why i cant do it like that:

```
if not name:
        return "One for you, one for me."
elif name:
    return f'One for {name}, one for me.'
```

for me is the same, but this method is screaming on me:

```
def test_no_name_given(self):
    self.assertEqual(two_fer(), "One for you, one for me.")

 self.assertEqual(two_fer(), "One for you, one for me.")
TypeError: two_fer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Can soemone explain me why? I understand the error but i dont get why. For me my second def function is same like first one.

Comment: I think both don't work, but the function head needs to be `def two_fer(name=None):`. This way only, you can omit the argument when calling it.

Comment: Otherwise, you have to explicitly pass the `None` (or at least non-truthy) value : `two_fer(None)` or `two_fer("")`.

Comment: I will learn more about that what you wrote. Coz for now i didnt use sth like name=none and to be honest dont know how it works. Anyway, my first def function worked fine and has been submited to exercism.

Answer (score 0):

You receive a TypeError, because you didn't apply any default value to your paramater `name` on your function:

```py
def two_fer(name=None):
    if name:
        return f'One for {name}, one for me.'
    elif not name:
        return "One for you, one for me."
```

The assert shows you:

```py
self.assertEqual(two_fer(), "One for you, one for me.")
```

that there is no argument supplied to `two_fer()` because the paranthesis are empty.

But you defined that `two_fer` needs to have an argument with:

```py
def two_fer(name):
    ...
```

And since you didn't supply any default value for `name` the interpreter tells you that there is one missing argument, if the assert is called.